# How to copy a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a file named as `new11` and `new12` and the path is `source=\Users\user.CLPSTPDFC46\Desktop\new11` and `dest=\Users\user.CLPSTPDFC46\Desktop\new12`

Now I need to copy the content from `new11` to `new12`. how can I approach this ?

Comment: do you want to append data in new12 or create new file ?

Comment: os.system('cp source dest')

Comment: want to append the data

Comment: please update the question & title, for append please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: Annoying that the duplicate link does not point to the duplicate. This is a content edit (seek/apend/merge). Not a file copy.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) it allows you to copy files.

Comment: and why it is downvoted

Comment: @VigneshKalai some people don't appreciate answers to really, **really** bad questions

Comment: Heh, I was wondering the same. I guess you're right.

Comment: guys you may be a professionals but i am a fresher to this okay

Comment: learn to use the search and you will be fine.